# Is it possible with Swift Mailer to send email message to a different address than is in the TO header?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

It's possible to send email to one address while another address is listed in the email's TO header. That is to say, Envelope-to and the TO header don't necessarily have to match. This makes it possible to send an email to someone but have the message appear to be addressed to another email address, which is useful if it's a forwarded message.

My issue, however, is that I'm not sure how to do this with Swift Mailer. It's easy enough to set different addresses in Envelope-from and the FROM header with setSender() and setFrom(), but it doesn't appear to be possible to do the same for Envelope-to and the TO header.

Am I just not looking in the right spot? Would it be possible to extend the library to achieve this, and if so, how?

Comment: Based on my research over the last few days, it's not possible with the library as is, and none of the plugins make it possible either. It appears the reason is that Swift Mailer makes the assumption that all recipient headers (TO, CC, and BCC) are meant to be actual recipients of the message. Not a bad assumption, I suppose, but the way the library is written, it's not possible to override this behavior without extending several classes with plenty of copies of Swift Mailer's methods. And that's not a good idea.

Comment: Simply put, I need to be able to include actual recipients in the RCPT TO: command and include only _apparent_ recipients (the ones displayed when you're looking at the message in your mail program) in the message headers. If anyone has any ideas on how to do that without touching the library itself, I'd be much obliged. I really wish I could offer a bounty for this one.